# Image flipped when using Dib Section to replace slow SetPixel()

Tags: c, winapi

I recently found this ([Win32 API Speed Issues](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/73204-win32-api-speed-issues.html))
to improve drawing speed, but it seems the code :

```
pBits[(y * WIDTH) + x] = RGB(0, 0, 0xFF);
```

always make the image flipped (from bottom-left to top-right),

Do you guys know how to fix this problem ??

.

Here's the flipped image:

[flipped-bitmap.png](https://bitbucket.org/SiraitX/win32-api/downloads/flipped-bitmap.png)

Here's my code :

```
for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<200; j++) {
        int x, y;
        cr1 = GetPixel(hdc_tmp, i*2, j*2);
        cr2 = GetPixel(hdc_tmp, i*2, 1+j*2);
        cr3 = GetPixel(hdc_tmp, 1+i*2, j*2);
        cr4 = GetPixel(hdc_tmp, 1+i*2, 1+j*2);

        red = (GetRValue(cr1) + GetRValue(cr2) + GetRValue(cr3) + GetRValue(cr4)) / 4;
        green = (GetGValue(cr1) + GetGValue(cr2) + GetGValue(cr3) + GetGValue(cr4)) / 4;
        blue = (GetBValue(cr1) + GetBValue(cr2) + GetBValue(cr3) + GetBValue(cr4)) / 4;

        pbits[i+j*200] = RGB(red, green, blue); // BUG ??
    }
}

BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 200, 200, hdc_aa, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common for a DIB section to be held in memory from the bottom scanline up.

You can either adjust your `pBits` index to write from the bottom row first, or change the sign of the height on the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` that describes the DIB section.

For example:

```
bmp.bmiHeader.biHeight = -HEIGHT;
```

The sign of the height determines whether or not the DIB section is treated as bottom-up or top-down.